# How to unarchive custom object to something other than custom class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedunarchiver

I have an object where we used `NSKeyedArchiver` to archive as class `Foo`

Then I changed the target name from `Apple` to `Orange`.  And it went into production and users started crashing on startup.  But not all.  And logs point to `NSKeyedUnarchiver`

I went and grabbed the archived `Foo` file from when the target was called `Apple` and when it was called `Orange` and converted to xml so I could read it.  The main and only difference (I think) is that the `classname` key is `Apple.Foo` and `Orange.Foo` respectively.

How can I get one of the archived files and check it's archived class name?

If I do `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: path) as? Foo` it will crash.

Ideally I'd so something like:

```
let object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: path) as? [String : Any] 
let name = object!["classname"]!
if name == "Apple.Foo" {
    //delete the cache and let it rebuild
}
```

But obviously it doesn't work like this.  Any ideas on how I can check that I have a corrupted file and get it deleted without the app crashing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll keep both classes, try an unarchived with both, and bridge to create on from the the other, and decide to save each time with the same class?

Comment: @Larme Issue is they are not different classes, they are the same.  But the class was archived with one target name, and unarchived as a different target name.  So the prefix to the class name is different.  It only crashes a percentage of users though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the last few days I learned that you can set two different class names for the unarchiver at the same time and they'll both work:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Foo.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "Apple.Foo")
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Foo.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "Orange.Foo")
```

Now it doesn't matter what classname the file actually has at the time of unarchiving.